# How to implement one method with different argument types?

Tags: java, oop

I should implement a four method to handle one specific objective for different types. I couldnot find a logical way how to implement it. At below code, should I create a abstract and extend relationship or just put them into one class and use method overriding ?

What do I want to manage is that just `call(argument)`. Internally, below methods should be called:

call `foo(String argument)` if argument is in type of String

call `foo(Map argument)` if argument is in type of Map

call `foo(Integer[] argument)` if argument is in type of Array of Integer

Comment: Have you looked at generics?

Comment: Is that all the types you want to allow? If so, just overload the method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in call(String argument), I am doing String related operations. IF there is a mechanism to check type of argument like `if type(argument) == String `, I will use generic method. Thanks

Comment: @clcto no; for future task, I will extend for other type.

Comment: For me, this sounds like questionable design in the first place. Maybe you should elaborate **what** exactly you want to do with these different objects.

Comment: @Marco13 for each type I will do specific operation namely `put them into appropriate format in order to package management system will handle it`

Comment: Just to let you know (as you asked), there is a mechanism to check the type of an object, you can use instanceof. However, I don't think it is the best answer here. for example, if(type instanceof String){...}else if(type instanceof Map){...}.

You could then use foo(Object obj) as the method and check the type. However, that would be horrible code IMO as you can pass objects which are not expected.

Comment: Even though the description is far too vague, there are still hundreds of possible alternatives to an (ugly, non-OO and not easily extensible) chain of `instanceof`-checks. One could consider a (type-safe!) solution involving some `Handler<T> { void handle(T t) }` interface, with impelementations like `StringHandler`, `MapHandler` etc. and a `Map<Class<?>, Handler<?>>`, but ... again, the question is too vague to give any profound hints here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IF there is a mechanism to check type of argument like if type(argument) == String , I will use generic method.

If I understand you, then yes - there is [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

```
public static <T> void myMethod(T obj) { // <-- generic type T
  if (obj instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("Printing String directly: " + (String) obj);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Printin String by toString(): " + obj.toString());
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  myMethod("Hello");
  myMethod(new Date());
}
```

Per the Java Tutorial link,

> The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

You don't really need generics here, so you might implement `myMethod()` like

```
public static void myMethod(Object obj) { // Any Object
  if (obj instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("Printing String directly: " + (String) obj);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Printin String by toString(): " + obj.toString());
  }
}
```

Finally, all of this distracts from the problem at hand - you should probably just use [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24999005/2970947) from [laune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2107876/laune).

Comment: That's an answer to the question about `type(argument) == String`, but I would really suggest on @laune's answer, because the overloading is much more clearer mechanism, than comparing types.

Comment: By the way, I really think, generics are nothing to do here (you just don't use their power), you may just use `Object obj`

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Edited. Better?

Comment: Yep, sure now it's better.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Awesome. Obviously function overloading doesn't work when you need to work with unknown types (instead of four *known* types).

Comment: When the type is unknown, you wouldn't need to enumerate types with the appropriate behavior as OP do.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch in fact, you can overload the method for the known types, and leave another with `Object o` for the unknown types.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple case of overloading. Just fill in the method bodies,

```
void foo(String argument){
}

void foo(Map argument){
}

void foo(Integer[] argument){
}
```

and a call like

```
obj.foo( something );
```

will work, depending on something being one of the three parameter classes.

(Of course, this works with static methods, too.)